# A generic error occurred in GDI+, PNG Image to MemoryStream

Tags: c#

Code:

```
var fullOutputPath = "~/Content/img/";
var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(str.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "").Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", ""));
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
{
      ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
      var image = Image.FromStream(ms);
      image.Save(fullOutputPath, ImageFormat.Png); 
}
```

Exception:

> "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Comment: A first step: set `ms.Position = 0;` after the Write()

Comment: And you'll have to Server.MapPath() that output filename.

Comment: Always post full error details, in this case the part of the stacktrace that shows on which line it went wrong is essential.

Comment: Additionally fullOutputPath points to directory - it should point to file instead like Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/mypicturename.png")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A generic error occurred in GDI+"
I am getting this error in 3 cases which are mention in below.

1. Check folder is exist.
2. Check folder permission. Remove permission read only from folder.
3. Check image upload path is correct.

Hope your issue will solve.
Happy coding :)

Thanks.